# Create a string in C# for SQL contains function in stored procedure

Tags: c#, sql-server, escaping

I have a stored procedure like this:

```
ALTER PROCEDURE autoCompleteFeedback
    @words varchar(255) 
AS
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON;

    SELECT DISTINCT TOP 5 * 
    FROM feedback 
    WHERE CONTAINS(feedbackMsg, @words)  
      AND NOT feedbackMsg LIKE '%Del%';
END
GO

EXEC autoCompleteFeedback '"*Who*"'
```

Works great

But now I want to pass a word from C# to my procedure

For example:

```
 string myString = "whooHoo";
 string auto = '"*+myString+*"';
 var a = nm.autoCompleteFeedback(auto).ToList();
```

I can't get the escape characters right, is it possible?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can escape the quotes with a backslash:

```
string auto = $"'\"*{myString}*\"'";
```

Or you can use the `@` symbol before your string to get a verbatim string literal. That way you can escape the quotes by using double quotes:

```
string auto = $@"'""*{myString}*""'";
```

In this case I'd go with the first option though because it's more readable in my opinion.

By using `$` you can insert variables into strings with braces:

```
string name = "Alexander";
string greet = $"Hello {name}";
//greet = "Hello Alexander"
```

Comment: yes but i want to add my variable in there mystring

Comment: You want to insert mystring into auto?

Comment: Edited my answer, by using `$` you can insert variables with braces

Answer (score 0):

There are two ways of scaping:

1. using backslash. To scape `"` you have to use `\"`
2. using `@"Your query"` Inside the query use `""` to scape the wuotes

The second options allows you to define a multiline string, like this:

```
var query= @"Alter PROCEDURE autoCompleteFeedback
-- Add the parameters for the stored procedure here
@words varchar(255) 

AS
BEGIN

SET NOCOUNT ON;
select distinct top 5  * from feedback where CONTAINS(feedbackMsg,@words)
AND NOT feedbackMsg LIKE '%Del%';

END
";
```

Important note: don't ever concat strings to execute SQL of any kind. Do always use parameters, or you'll be exposed to SQL injection attacks.

Answer (score 0):

Simplest answer;

```
string myString = "whooHoo";
string auto = "'\"*" + myString + "*\"'";

Console.WriteLine(myString); // whooHoo
Console.WriteLine(auto); // '"*whooHoo*"'
```